# posting JSON object to a Restful web service

Tags: ios, restkit, afnetworking, restkit-0.20, afjsonrequestoperation

I have two `Restful` web services:
**service1**: `api.wego.com/flights/api/k/2/searches` and
**service2**: `api.wego.com/flights/api/k/2/fares`

**service1's question:**
I want to use `AFJSONRequestOperation` to do a `POST` request to **serivce1** , the using of `AFJSONRequestOperation` instead of `RestKit` with this service is because I don't need to create any mapping for the returned response, I simply just want to save some of the returned data into local variables, but the problem is that **service1** expects something like this `JSON` in the post body:

`{

       "trips": [
    {

      "departure_code": "SIN",

      "arrival_code": "HKG",

      "outbound_date": "2013-11-29",

      "inbound_date": "2013-12-06"

    }
  ],

  "adults_count": 1

}`

**the question:** how to create an `AFJSONRequestOperation` to post a request to **service1** and send the above `JSON` with the post body ?

**service2's question:**
I want to use `RestKit 0.2x` to do a `POST` request to this service, I know how to build up the mapping model, but according to the service docs, I have to send a `JSON` object along with the post body that looks like this:

`{

  "id": "1376967853520",

  "search_id": "IAXutjj0TAu0Wq-kvOMK6A",

  "trip_id": "NYC:LON:2013-11-29:2013-12-06",

  "fares_query_type": "route"

}`

I used `RestKit` previously to do `Get` requests using `getObjectsAtPath` method, but in this case I think I have to use `postObject` method to do the `POST` request but I'm not sure of that.

**the question**: how to do a `POST` request to **service2** using `RestKit 0.2x` and send the above `JSON` with the post body (considering that the mapping model is already set and ready to be used) ?

thank you so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a dictionary and use `NSJSONSerialisation` (This would produce data for you to set as the operation payload). Or, use `RKObjectManager requestWithObject:method:path:parameters:` (which would create the URL request to send, with the payload data already set). Then create the request operation with that.
2. Yes, use the `RKObjectManager postObject:...` method. You need to create request mapping and descriptor for the class of object you're going to post. Then just post with the object and path.

Comment: 1: NSJSONSerialisation ? would you elaborate a little bit more ? 2: how to send a json object with postObject method ?